# Can I use d3.scales to evenly distribute circles of varying size

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, scale

I am interested in understanding how to use d3.js to evenly distribute svg circles of varying size by using one of d3's scale functions. Right now, I have code that creates the circles; and I am using d3.scale.ordinal() for my x-scale and the circles are evenly spaced numerically (from the center of one circle to the center of the other), but not visually. I am slowly teaching myself JavaScript and would appreciate any help you can offer.

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20},
    w = 700 -  margin.left - margin.right,
    h = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var numbers = [86, 57, 112, 293, 75, 1, 45];


var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(numbers.length)) 
    .rangeRoundBands([0, w], .8); 


var rScale = d3.scale.sqrt()
    .domain([0, d3.max(numbers)])
    .range([10, 60]);      

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom); 

svg.selectAll("circle")
     .data(numbers)
    .enter().append("circle")
     .attr("cy", h/2)
     .attr("cx", function(d,i) { return xScale(i); })
     .attr("r", function(d) { return rScale(d); })
     .style("fill", "#ccc");


svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(numbers)
    .enter().append("text")
    .text(function(d){ return d; })
    .attr("y", h/2 + 5 )
    .attr("x", function(d,i){ return xScale(i); })
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", "11px")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style("fill", "#000000");
```

Comment: You don't even need D3 for this. Take the total length, subtract the sum of the diameters of your circles. This gives you the length available for gaps. Divide that by (number of circles - 1). This will give you the gap between each pair of circles. The center of a circle is now determined by the length of this gap + radius of circle on the left + radius of circle on the right.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, if you please, how then do I use that number in my code? I am guessing that I need a new function (to replace xScale) that contains a for loop. I have made a fiddle, would you be able to demonstrate? [fiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/gailz7152013/3bd50yx2/14/#&togetherjs=QuDtlcDewE)

Comment: Well it would look something like `var gap = (w - d3.sum(numbers.map(function(d) { return rScale(d) * 2; })) / (numbers.length - 1); var positions = [0]; for(var i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) { pos[i] = rScale(numbers[i-1]) + gap + rScale(numbers[i]) + pos[i-1]; }`. Then `positions` gives you the centers of the circles.

Comment: Is there a way to control the x position of the very first circle? Right now, it's set to 0.

Comment: Yes. Set it to something that's not 0.

Comment: That is what I have now, but if the circles change in diameter, my extra padding doesn't work as well.

Comment: Well, it should work with the code I've posted. If you're using different code, you'll have to show us.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gailz7152013/yf02nmk1/

This is what the code looks like right now...

Comment: Ok, you have to subtract the offset from the total width: https://jsfiddle.net/yf02nmk1/5/

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be more elegant to define another scale for the circle centers - this way, you could use it for both the circles and the text. Note that this doesn't replace your `xScale`, but rather appears before it.

Calculate the sum of the circles`diameters using the`numbers` array (it is twice the sum; see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)). call the result totalDiams.

Now define `xCenterScale` like

```
var xCenterScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(numbers.length)) 
    .range([numbers[0], totalDiams - numbers[numbers.length - 1]);
```

Now your center for circle `i` is `xScale(xCenterScale(i))`.

Comment: thank you for that step-by-step. I appreciated it, but I could not make it work.

Comment: No problem. If you like, write what didn't work exactly.

Comment: thank you. I'm sure I am just doing something wrong because I am inexperienced. Based on the Developer Tools, "cx" is no longer registered; so the circles all share (0,0) coordinates. I have been working on a fiddle here: [link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gailz7152013/2zg1Lmkm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Solution for height (it should be the same for width):

Find out total needed height and divide by 2, then find out total height of your elements(and gaps) and divide that with 2. And then subtract first with the second value, eg:

```
var totalHeight = 1000; // px
var centerAxis = totalHeight / 2; // 500
var totalHeightOfElementsAndGaps = 300;
var halfHeigthOfElementsAndGaps = totalHeightOfElementsAndGaps / 2; // 150
var positionOfFirstElement = centerAxis - halfHeigthOfElements; // 500-150=350
```

Note that number of gaps is equal to number of elements minus 1.